# Optimizing command line GIMP

Tags: gimp

I am running a script-fu macro using GIMP from the command line. However, it is quite slow to startup and run - about 20-25 seconds. I think a lot of this time is spent on startup - loading all the plugins and such. What are some ways to optimize GIMP on the CL? Is there any way to keep it always running?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some promising options from the [GIMP docs](http://docs.gimp.org/en/gimp-fire-up.html) (some of which you may already be using):

> **--no-interface**: Run without a user interface.
>       **--no-data**: Do not load patterns, gradients, palettes, or brushes. Often useful in non-interactive situations where start-up time is to be minimized.
>       **--no-fonts**: Do not load any fonts. This is useful to load GIMP faster for scripts that do not use fonts, or to find problems related to malformed fonts that hang GIMP.
>       **--no-splash**: Do not show the splash screen while starting.

The [GIMP FAQ](http://www.netads.com/~meo/gimp/faq-user.html#slow):

> *The GIMP takes too long to load - how can I speed it up?*
>
> The main things are to make sure you are running at least version 1.0, and make sure you compiled with optimization on, debugging turned off, and the shared memory and X shared memory options turned on.
>
> Or, buy a faster system with more memory. 8^)

[This question on SuperUser](https://superuser.com/q/238773/13669) addresses slow GIMP startup time in general and recommends:

- Rebuild the font cache file by deleting `C:\Documents and Settings\<username>\.fonts-cache1` and then opening GIMP.
- Check for slow-loading plugins by starting up with `--verbose` and seeing where it hangs.  Then remove problematic plugins by renaming them in `C:\Program Files\GIMP-2.0\lib\gimp\<version>\plug-ins`.  Alternately, remove all plugins by renaming the whole plugins folder.

Answer (score 3):

Not so much a solution as a different possibility for the future, but have you considered not using GIMP?

GIMP is first and foremost a GUI-based app.  If you're doing a lot of repetitive image manipulation from the command line, you might be better off with a tool like [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/) that's designed expressly for such use.  I don't know how complex your script-fu scripts are, or how easily they could be translated to ImageMagick's (admittedly complex) syntax, but you definitely wouldn't have problems with long startup time.

Answer (score 0):

You could use "Script-fu Server" .

image window > Main menu > filters > script-fu > Start server.

You will be provided with a popup asking for the port to run it in. There is also "help" provided on the same popup, which also describes the protocol used by the server.